# Python selenium webdriver read email address from response of java script

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Below code open one url using and clicks on one button. The button shows email id. I am trying to grab that email id however not sure how to do that. Kindly help.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/work/scripts/chromedriver')
url = "https://bloomington.craigslist.org/reo/d/bloomington-do-you-need-to-sell-mobile/7004269066.html"
self.browser.get(url)
rebtn = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('reply-button')
rebtn.click()
self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('mailapp').text
```

Error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".mailapp"}

Comment: What's wrong the code currently? What have you tried? Please take a look at [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11301900).

Comment: `find_element_by_class_name('mailapp').text`

Comment: I tried this already but got below error,

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".mailapp"}

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I tried the solution given by Amit before posting this question. I also gone through the documentation on how the click functionality works but nothing has helped.

Comment: @KalpeshTawde what have you done to debug? The error message says which element it can't find, that's quite useful, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you wrong about `reply` button selector, and need a bit wait after click `reply` button:

```
rebtn = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.reply-button.js-only')
rebtn.click()
#here, seconds
self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('mailapp').text
```

[Documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)